# Finding the expectation of two absolutely continuous variables that doesn't have a joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I'm having yet *another* confusion with my probability homework and I would love some help.

3.2.5: $X$ follows Uniform$[3,7]$, $Y$ follows Exponent$(9)$. Find $\mathop{{}\mathbb{E}}(-5X -6Y).$

3.2.6: $X$ follows Uniform$[-12,-9]$, $Y$ follows N$(-8,9)$. Find $\mathop{{}\mathbb{E}}(11X+14Y+3).$

For the life of me, I don't understand how 3.2.5 $\neq 5E(X) + -6E(Y)$, and how 3.2.6 $\neq 11E(X)+14E(Y)+3$. I must be missing some theory here.  Is there a theorem that could help me out?

Comment: ??? what makes you think that those are not equal?

Comment: Stupid answer key! I've done this and checked the solution using Michael J. Evans and Jeffrey S. Rosenthal's answer key and I thought I had made some mistake. Now I see that the only mistake made was reading the textbook in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties) does not require the random variables to be independent.  For *any* random variables $X$, $Y$ with finite expectation, and for any scalars $a, b, c$, we have $$\operatorname{E}[aX + bY + c] = a \operatorname{E}[X] + b \operatorname{E}[Y] + c.$$